# Not able to use websockets module with multiple websocket connection

Tags: python, websocket

Below code works fine one connection . But failed when number of connection is 2

```
import asyncio
import websockets

USERS = []
async def differnt():
    await USERS[0].send("Your name is ")
    name=await USERS[0].recv()
    print (name)
    await USERS[0].send("Your name is "+name) 

    if len(USERS) ==2:
        await USERS[1].send("Your name is ")
        name=await USERS[1].recv()
        print (name)
        await USERS[1].send("Your name is "+name)


async def counter(websocket, path):
    USERS.append(websocket)
    print (USERS)
    await differnt()

start_server = websockets.serve(counter, "localhost", 6789)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

As soon as second connection added , it wont work . shows

```
    await USERS[0].send("Your name is ")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 555, in send
    await self.ensure_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 803, in ensure_open
    raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), no reason
```

Comment: It's the same `start_server` instance in both uses, two connections need two separate instances of the client.

Comment: One server can only communicate (both send and receive) with only one client ? Do I need to start another server in different port ?